# Magento 2 Wrong success page loading after checkout

Tags: magento2.4

i have a custom success page on my site which was working fine but recently i have added a new payment processor (Paytm) and since then the site is loading their basic success page. Can someone please guide me how to redirect to my old page. Thanks

Comment: If the new payment method is overriding the success page you will need to override that page in your template.

Comment: I was trying to figure this out. could you be a bit more specific how to overide in my template

Answer (score 0):

You have to check the following things, which help you into this one.

1. In new payment method `(Paytm)`, after order placed, it is hard coded to redirect on success page.
2. Kindly confirm if hard coded found, then it redirect on which URL and make it correct if your new page other things.
3. Also confirm, new payment method override that same things into there extension and due to that it redirect on old checkout page.